# How to partition set of items into subsets with similar mean, variance and number of elements - looking for some help

Tags: r, clustering, algorithms, partitioning

***Short version:***
Given I have a list of 120 traits (happy, sad, etc.) evaluated on a number of scales ranging from -5 (for example highly negative) to +5 (for example highly positive), how can I group these traits into 6 sets of 20 items each, so that each set has a similar mean and variance of those scales?

***A word of explanation:***
The 120 traits will be judged on whether or not they describe one of 6 social objects (20 traits per object) (using a 1-5 scale). Traits I will be using come from a bigger set (of 300 unique items) where each has been evaluated on measures like: valence, agency, communion and a couple of others.

I'd like to make sure that each social object was judged on traits that overall had a similar mean and (possibly) standard deviation, so that I don't end up, with one object that had very extreme traits (highly negative and highly positive) while others where somewhere in the middle.

*R data example:*

This is a minimal data example.
Note that in my real data, measures (valence etc) are not necessarily normally distributed and most likely correlated with other measures.

I did some reading and found out my problem might be partitioning related.
Here is a `R` code I made up that does (more or less) what I'd like, but only based on one variable (let's pretented x are ratings of valence).

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
x<- rnorm(120) # normal distribution is just an example
x<- sort(x)
g1<- rep(1:6, 20) # grouping strategy 1
g2<- rep(c(1:6, 6:1), 10) # grouping strategy 2
df<- tibble(x, g1, g2)


df %>%
    group_by(g1) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(x), var = var(x))

df %>%
    group_by(g2) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(x), var = var(x))
```

With the above code I can see that strategy #2 yields better results, as means of groups are more similar than with strategy #1. q

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     g1       mean       var
  <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 0.01216328 0.8462127
2     2 0.05113158 0.8146632
3     3 0.08567107 0.7907553
4     4 0.13632257 0.7679591
5     5 0.16613787 0.7915441
6     6 0.20683895 0.8273733

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     g2      mean       var
  <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 0.1078368 0.9842131
2     2 0.1094842 0.8930841
3     3 0.1104103 0.8232504
4     4 0.1115834 0.7368137
5     5 0.1077852 0.7200830
6     6 0.1111654 0.7093138
```

What I can't figure out is how to work with a couple of ranking variables (above example had only `x`).

In other words, what would be the best strategy to find the best possible grouping solution for a dataframe like this:

```
data<- data.frame(
      trait_number = seq(1:120), 
      valence_rating = rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 3),
      agency_rating = rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 3),
      communion_rating = rnorm(120, mean = 0, sd = 3),
      grouping = NA)
```

(note: once again rnorm is just an example for sample data. My real data is not normally distributed)

If I can explain anything more, please let me know in comments.
Thank you.

Comment: This thing is really bugging me and I would love to offer a bounty if only I could.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  Given the data in your R code, you want to divide up the observations into groups?  Like, group 1 would be observations with valence around -1, agency around 1, and communion around 0.  Group 2 would be observations with valence around 2, agency around 0, and communion around 0.  Etc?  Like that or something else?

Comment: Thanks for stopping by Bill. No that's (probably) not what I want. I'd like to get 6 sets of 20 elements each, where valence, agency and communion have similar mean and variance between and within those 6 sets. In other words I'd like to get set as similar as possible to each other.

Comment: OK, got it.  If you just want the theoretical distributions in the sub-samples to be the same, then dividing the sample randomly does that.  So, I assume you want the empirical distributions of the variables to be the same in the different sub-samples.  Right?  Like, you want both the population means and the sample means to be the same, not just the population means.

Comment: Bill I just finished editing my original post with more code and strategies I came up with, would like to take a look at it? Answering your question: I would like to avoid random sampling and go for a strategy finding the best possible (optimal) solution. One important thing to note here: valence, agency and communion ratings are not normally distributed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something I know about.  I googled and found that this is a topic which comes up in cross-validation.  The paper I link below suggests an algorithm which is 1) choose an element randomly and assign it to set 1.  2) find the closest 5 elements to the one you chose in step 1 and assign these to sets 2 through 6.  3) keep doing this until you run out of elements or your sets are full.  You need to operationalize closest in step 2 with some distance measure.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jose_Moreno-Torres/publication/262148983_Study_on_the_Impact_of_Partition-Induced_Dataset_Shift_on_-Fold_Cross-Validation/links/00b7d53787aa38e412000000/Study-on-the-Impact-of-Partition-Induced-Dataset-Shift-on-Fold-Cross-Validation.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: `for a dataframe like this:`, and then follows some code, not the data. It is a very bad practice to not show data, only to show uncommented code, R in this instance, - because some people may be not R users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a mutlivariate nonparametric regression method that uses clusters.  Using the cluster ID's to sort the data, then assigning a group to that sorted data yields the following results with your `data` df:

```
require(NNS)

a=NNS.reg(cbind(data$valence_rating,data$agency_rating,data$communion_rating),
      rep(1,length(data$trait_number)))$Fitted.xy

setkey(a,NNS.ID)

colnames(a)[1:3]=colnames(data[,2:4])


# Re-run from here with different group innovations
a[,`:=` (group=rep(1:6, 20))]

a[,{valence_mean=mean(valence_rating);valence_sd=sd(valence_rating)
    agency_mean=mean(agency_rating);agency_sd=sd(agency_rating)
    communion_mean=mean(communion_rating);communion_sd=sd(communion_rating)
    list(valence_mean=valence_mean,valence_sd=valence_sd,
         agency_mean=agency_mean,agency_sd=agency_sd,
         communion_mean=communion_mean,communion_sd=communion_sd)
    }, by=group]



   group valence_mean valence_sd agency_mean agency_sd communion_mean communion_sd
1:     1  -0.06839077   2.674746 -0.61403779  3.024703     -0.1573398     2.455025
2:     2  -0.73164854   3.603836 -0.06347979  2.197635      0.5897524     3.638972
3:     3   0.87995369   2.425216 -0.70785458  2.915249     -0.1070705     3.266067
4:     4   0.34903443   2.667286 -0.67996477  3.295273      0.4793330     2.250582
5:     5   0.32653867   3.204289  0.35996665  3.191802      0.5791942     3.786095
6:     6   0.82249408   3.037100 -0.18225506  3.531984     -0.3244441     3.280554
```

I'm sure it could be better, but hopefully this gets you started and it's applicable to your actual data.